# What cognizable limits are there in Articulatory phonetics?

Tags: phonetics

For example, I know that the tone component (like in Chinese) is absent in speech as it varies from time to time (it also depends on situation). 
Considering vowels there's an agreement to check only tongue posture and placement (as mouth cavity also varies).

Maybe there is also some aerodynamic limits on the quantity of exhaling air (tongue movements, muscle strength etc...)

My question is important because when I start learning something its hard to tell the limits of study of any subject. When I have a look at Wikipedia or any other dictionary it doesn't tell mathematically (or so, I mean precisely) when the field of study starts where it ends and which is the smallest examined learning material which could be taken into consideration.
Geometry of mouth, race question, unit of measurement, boundary of experiments (for example the modelling artificial speech uses a brand-new MRI scans techniques which by themselves imposes some math background limits).

Comment: This is very broad and philosophical. To make it more specific and therefore answerable, what do you mean by 'cognizable' (are there other limits you don't care about)? What is 'varies from time to time' (too vague)? What is 'Mb'? Do you just want to know what label 'articulatory phonetics' is limited to, as different from other branches of phonetics?

Comment: @Xsi, it's hard to understand what the question here is. It seems to be about limits to the field of articulatory phonetics, but conflates methodological limits to the study (a researcher's choice to primarily consider tongue position in vowel production), physiological limits of speech production (aerodynamic and myodynamic), and limits of the field itself.
As Mitch says, the question must become specific. What boundaries should be discussed?